# calculating percentage and displaying correct answer for online examination website in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an online examination website project in asp.net and I want to calculate the percentage of correct answers as well as the final score to display (multiplying [marks] and no of correct answers).

Here is my code (it only displays correct answers not the incorrect answers):

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString2"].ConnectionString);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from [Biology]", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt2);
    grdquestions.DataSource = dt2;
    grdquestions.DataBind();  
}
protected void examsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int correctAnswers = 0, incorrectAnswers = 0,
    totalQuestions = grdquestions.Rows.Count;
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from [Biology]", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);


   for(int i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++)
    {
      GridViewRow row = grdquestions.Rows[i];
    string answer = dt.Rows[i]["Answer"].ToString();

  var radioButtons = new List<RadioButton>
   {
    (RadioButton)row.FindControl("Option1"),
    (RadioButton)row.FindControl("Option2"),
    (RadioButton)row.FindControl("Option3"),
    (RadioButton)row.FindControl("Option4"),
    };

foreach (var radioButton in radioButtons)
{
    if (radioButton != null)
    {
        if (radioButton.Checked)
        {
            if (radioButton.Text == answer)
                correctAnswers++;
            else
            {
                incorrectAnswers++;

                radioButton.Checked = false;
            }

        }
        else if (radioButton.Text == answer)
        {
            radioButton.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}
string correctAnswerPercentage = (correctAnswers / totalQuestions).ToString("0.00%");
Response.Write(correctAnswerPercentage);
        }

Comment: Please edit the question and add a question or problem description. What part is the problem?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? You don't know how to calculate percentages?

Comment: i know how to calculate it but i need to get no of incorrect answers?

Comment: I haven't used Response.Write`, so i can't help you with that and Web related stuff has no longer anything to do with the original question. But i edited my answer to also include the mark calculation.

Comment: this is  not included in the code , the only thing i want is the display the percentage i hope u can help me bro!

Comment: @AhmedHosny where do you want to display it? Just set the Text of your Label for the percentage to `correctAnswerPercentage`.

Comment: @BoredomOverload yes brother but  i am facing null reference exception (object reference not set to an instance of object )

Comment: @AhmedHosny for what are you getting this exception?

Comment: @BoredomOverload i don know but  its throwing in this line "if (radioButton.Checked)"

Comment: @AhmedHosny Debug and check if `radioButtons` contains items that are null. And if so make sure that your `(RadioButton)row.FindControl("Option1")` returns what you expect.

Comment: radioButtons contains 4 rows and (RadioButton)row.FindControl("Option1") returns what we expected but radionButton in "if (radioButton.Checked)" -contains null ...... ?

Comment: i fixed the null reference exception but its still displaying final score =0 ....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
int correctAnswers = 0, incorrectAnswers = 0,
    totalMarks = 0, totalQuestions = grdquestions.Rows.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++)
{
    GridViewRow row = grdquestions.Rows[i];
    string answer = dt.Rows[i]["Answer"].ToString();
    int marks = (int)dt.Rows[i]["Marks"];

    var radioButtons = new List<RadioButton>
    {
        (RadioButton)row.FindControl("Option1"),
        (RadioButton)row.FindControl("Option2"),
        (RadioButton)row.FindControl("Option3"),
        (RadioButton)row.FindControl("Option4")
    }

    foreach (var radioButton in radioButtons)
    {
        if (radioButton.Checked)
        {
            if (radioButton.Text == answer)
            {
                correctAnswers++;
                totalMarks += marks;
            }
            else
            {
                incorrectAnswers++;
                radioButton.Checked = false;
            }
        }
        else if (radioButton.Text == answer)
        {
            radioButton.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}

Label2.Text = "FinalScore is :" + totalMarks;

string correctAnswerPercentage = (correctAnswers / totalQuestions).ToString("0.00%");
```

Comment: @AhmedHosny ah, then you need to do this calculation outside of the loop.

Comment: sorry to ask this but its not displaying any thing even after calculating outside the loop

Comment: @AhmedHosny could you edit your question and post your current code, so i can take a look at it?

Comment: ok i will edit my first question

Comment: check it out i edited the question